# Gray Exclamation Point when importing raw photos

Tags: macos, photos

I have been having difficulty with importing RAW photos from my Canon EOS 77D. I am able to see the thumbnail of all photos (which leads me to believe that perhaps photos can process my images.)
[image]

But when I click on a photo, I get the following (Please ignore the high ISO):[image]

What can I do so that I can see/edit my photos?

Answer (score 2):

I checked Apple's [Digital camera RAW formats supported by iOS 10 and macOS Sierra](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT207049) page and at present the Canon EOS 77D is not listed in terms of RAW format support.

I expect that support for your RAW format will be included in a future iOS and macOS software update.

In the meantime I would recommend you:

- provide [feedback](https://www.apple.com/feedback/photos.html) to Apple
- use one of the other formats